# How to know the image size after applying aspect fit for the image in an UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage, aspect-ratio

I am loading an image to an imageview with mode as 'Aspect Fit'. I need to know the size to which my image is being scaled to. Please help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

***Please see @Paul-de-Lange's answer instead of this one***

---

I couldn't find anything in an easily accessible variable that had this, so here is the brute force way:

```
- (CGSize) aspectScaledImageSizeForImageView:(UIImageView *)iv image:(UIImage *)im {

float x,y;
float a,b;
x = iv.frame.size.width;
y = iv.frame.size.height;
a = im.size.width;
b = im.size.height;

if ( x == a && y == b ) {           // image fits exactly, no scaling required
    // return iv.frame.size;
}
else if ( x > a && y > b ) {         // image fits completely within the imageview frame
    if ( x-a > y-b ) {              // image height is limiting factor, scale by height
        a = y/b * a;
        b = y;
    } else {
        b = x/a * b;                // image width is limiting factor, scale by width
        a = x;
    }
} 
else if ( x < a && y < b ) {        // image is wider and taller than image view
    if ( a - x > b - y ) {          // height is limiting factor, scale by height
        a = y/b * a;
        b = y;
    } else {                        // width is limiting factor, scale by width
        b = x/a * b;
        a = x;
    }
}
else if ( x < a && y > b ) {        // image is wider than view, scale by width
    b = x/a * b;
    a = x;
}
else if ( x > a && y < b ) {        // image is taller than view, scale by height
    a = y/b * a;
    b = y;
}
else if ( x == a ) {
    a = y/b * a;
    b = y;
} else if ( y == b ) {
    b = x/a * b;
    a = x;
}
return CGSizeMake(a,b);

}
```

Comment: This code is not accurate. It doesn't handle all cases. For example if  you have a 2048 x 1536 image and try and fit into 514 x 402. It will return the scaled size of 402 (height) when it should scale it to the width.  I changed `if ( a - x > b - y ) {`  to  `if ( a - x > b - y && (y/b * a) < x) {` to fix it. They other statements should be checked too.

Comment: Hello Sir, I found this Anser Helpful but can you pls help me in my Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727615/ios-get-framing-of-visible-part-of-uiimage-from-uiimageview

Answer (score 147):

Why not use the OS function [AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/1390116-avmakerectwithaspectratioinsider)?

Comment: This is exactly what is needed -- `[imageView setFrame:AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(image.size, imageView.frame)]`)

Comment: Good and clean option. Here is the docs link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Don't want to include the AVFoundation framework? I'm posting two alternative utility functions to `AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect()` in a separate answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The accepted answer above is not correct and wont work in different cases.

Comment: For swifters: import AVFoundation       let height = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect((image?.size)!, imageView.frame).height

Answer (score 56):

I wanted to use `AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect()` *without including the AVFoundation framework*.

So I've implemented the following two utility functions:

```
CGSize CGSizeAspectFit(CGSize aspectRatio, CGSize boundingSize)
{
    float mW = boundingSize.width / aspectRatio.width;
    float mH = boundingSize.height / aspectRatio.height;
    if( mH < mW )
        boundingSize.width = boundingSize.height / aspectRatio.height * aspectRatio.width;
    else if( mW < mH )
        boundingSize.height = boundingSize.width / aspectRatio.width * aspectRatio.height;
    return boundingSize;
}

CGSize CGSizeAspectFill(CGSize aspectRatio, CGSize minimumSize)
{
    float mW = minimumSize.width / aspectRatio.width;
    float mH = minimumSize.height / aspectRatio.height;
    if( mH > mW )
        minimumSize.width = minimumSize.height / aspectRatio.height * aspectRatio.width;
    else if( mW > mH )
        minimumSize.height = minimumSize.width / aspectRatio.width * aspectRatio.height;
    return minimumSize;
}
```

**Edit: Optimized below by removing duplicate divisions.**

```
CGSize CGSizeAspectFit(const CGSize aspectRatio, const CGSize boundingSize)
{
    CGSize aspectFitSize = CGSizeMake(boundingSize.width, boundingSize.height);
    float mW = boundingSize.width / aspectRatio.width;
    float mH = boundingSize.height / aspectRatio.height;
    if( mH < mW )
        aspectFitSize.width = mH * aspectRatio.width;
    else if( mW < mH )
        aspectFitSize.height = mW * aspectRatio.height;
    return aspectFitSize;
}

CGSize CGSizeAspectFill(const CGSize aspectRatio, const CGSize minimumSize)
{
    CGSize aspectFillSize = CGSizeMake(minimumSize.width, minimumSize.height);
    float mW = minimumSize.width / aspectRatio.width;
    float mH = minimumSize.height / aspectRatio.height;
    if( mH > mW )
        aspectFillSize.width = mH * aspectRatio.width;
    else if( mW > mH )
        aspectFillSize.height = mW * aspectRatio.height;
    return aspectFillSize;
}
```

**End of edit**

This takes a given size (first parameter) and maintains its aspect ratio. It then fills the given bounds (second parameter) as much as possible without violating the aspect ratio.

Using this to answer the original question:

```
// Using aspect fit, scale the image (size) to the image view's size.
CGSize sizeBeingScaledTo = CGSizeAspectFit(theImage.size, theImageView.frame.size);
```

Note how the image determines the aspect ratio, while the image view determines the size to be filled.

Feedback is very welcome.

Comment: This can be adjusted to use `CGFloats` if you're into that sort of thing.

Comment: Excellent answer.  You can also adjust it to center on a certain view, to get the actual CGRect of an image inside a UIImageView with AspectFit.  I did something like this:
<code>
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeAspectFit(imageView.image.size, imageView.frame.size);
    CGRect actualImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    actualImageRect.origin.x = imageView.center.x - imageSize.width / 2;
actualImageRect.origin.y = imageView.center.y - imageSize.height / 2;
</code>

Comment: Thank you, this is a great utility function.

Comment: I have included an optimized version that removes the duplicate divisions. Now a branchless equivalent might be a fun challenge to come up with. :)

Answer (score 18):

This simple function will calculate size of image after aspect fit:

**Swift 5.1**

```
extension UIImageView {

    var imageSizeAfterAspectFit: CGSize {
        var newWidth: CGFloat
        var newHeight: CGFloat

        guard let image = image else { return frame.size }

        if image.size.height >= image.size.width {
            newHeight = frame.size.height
            newWidth = ((image.size.width / (image.size.height)) * newHeight)

            if CGFloat(newWidth) > (frame.size.width) {
                let diff = (frame.size.width) - newWidth
                newHeight = newHeight + CGFloat(diff) / newHeight * newHeight
                newWidth = frame.size.width
            }
        } else {
            newWidth = frame.size.width
            newHeight = (image.size.height / image.size.width) * newWidth

            if newHeight > frame.size.height {
                let diff = Float((frame.size.height) - newHeight)
                newWidth = newWidth + CGFloat(diff) / newWidth * newWidth
                newHeight = frame.size.height
            }
        }
        return .init(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
    }
}
```

Objective C:

```
 -(CGSize)imageSizeAfterAspectFit:(UIImageView*)imgview{


    float newwidth;
    float newheight;

    UIImage *image=imgview.image;

    if (image.size.height>=image.size.width){
        newheight=imgview.frame.size.height;
        newwidth=(image.size.width/image.size.height)*newheight;

        if(newwidth>imgview.frame.size.width){
            float diff=imgview.frame.size.width-newwidth;
            newheight=newheight+diff/newheight*newheight;
            newwidth=imgview.frame.size.width;
        }

    }
    else{
        newwidth=imgview.frame.size.width;
        newheight=(image.size.height/image.size.width)*newwidth;

        if(newheight>imgview.frame.size.height){
            float diff=imgview.frame.size.height-newheight;
            newwidth=newwidth+diff/newwidth*newwidth;
            newheight=imgview.frame.size.height;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"image after aspect fit: width=%f height=%f",newwidth,newheight);


    //adapt UIImageView size to image size
    //imgview.frame=CGRectMake(imgview.frame.origin.x+(imgview.frame.size.width-newwidth)/2,imgview.frame.origin.y+(imgview.frame.size.height-newheight)/2,newwidth,newheight);

    return CGSizeMake(newwidth, newheight);

}
```

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me. But this answer did. And the real beauty of this answer is that it does not need to pass any explicit reference of the UIImage, instead, it takes it from the image content of the UIImageView. It works with orientation change either. Thanks.

Comment: Since this is always done on a UIImageView, it might be worth shaping it into a category method UIImageView.

Comment: it is not returning exact frame

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 3** Human Readable Version

```
extension UIImageView {

    /// Find the size of the image, once the parent imageView has been given a contentMode of .scaleAspectFit
    /// Querying the image.size returns the non-scaled size. This helper property is needed for accurate results.
    var aspectFitSize: CGSize {
        guard let image = image else { return CGSize.zero }

        var aspectFitSize = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)
        let newWidth: CGFloat = frame.size.width / image.size.width
        let newHeight: CGFloat = frame.size.height / image.size.height

        if newHeight < newWidth {
            aspectFitSize.width = newHeight * image.size.width
        } else if newWidth < newHeight {
            aspectFitSize.height = newWidth * image.size.height
        }

        return aspectFitSize
    }

    /// Find the size of the image, once the parent imageView has been given a contentMode of .scaleAspectFill
    /// Querying the image.size returns the non-scaled, vastly too large size. This helper property is needed for accurate results.
    var aspectFillSize: CGSize {
        guard let image = image else { return CGSize.zero }

        var aspectFillSize = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)
        let newWidth: CGFloat = frame.size.width / image.size.width
        let newHeight: CGFloat = frame.size.height / image.size.height

        if newHeight > newWidth {
            aspectFillSize.width = newHeight * image.size.width
        } else if newWidth > newHeight {
            aspectFillSize.height = newWidth * image.size.height
        }

        return aspectFillSize
    }

}
```

Comment: How about image origin position instead of Size?

Answer (score 11):

I also wanted to calculate height after the aspect ratio is applied to be able to calculate the height of table view's cell. So, I achieved via little math

```
ratio = width / height
```

and height would become

```
height = width / ratio
```

So code snippet would be

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anImage"];
float aspectRatio = img.size.width/img.size.height;
float requiredHeight = self.view.bounds.size.width / aspectRatio;
```

Comment: Elegant. I use it inside `UITableViewCell` class, so the `requiredHeight` becomes `float requiredHeight =  self.bounds.size.width / aspectRatio;`.

Comment: You are brilliant! This should have been the accepted answer!

Answer (score 9):

**For Swift use below code**

```
func imageSizeAspectFit(imgview: UIImageView) -> CGSize {
        var newwidth: CGFloat
        var newheight: CGFloat
        let image: UIImage = imgFeed.image!

        if image.size.height >= image.size.width {
            newheight = imgview.frame.size.height;
            newwidth = (image.size.width / image.size.height) * newheight
            if newwidth > imgview.frame.size.width {
                let diff: CGFloat = imgview.frame.size.width - newwidth
                newheight = newheight + diff / newheight * newheight
                newwidth = imgview.frame.size.width
            }
        }
        else {
            newwidth = imgview.frame.size.width
            newheight = (image.size.height / image.size.width) * newwidth
            if newheight > imgview.frame.size.height {
                let diff: CGFloat = imgview.frame.size.height - newheight
                newwidth = newwidth + diff / newwidth * newwidth
                newheight = imgview.frame.size.height
            }
        }

       print(newwidth, newheight)
        //adapt UIImageView size to image size
        return CGSizeMake(newwidth, newheight)
    }
```

**And Call Function**

```
imgFeed.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string:"Your image URL")))
self.imageSizeAfterAspectFit(imgFeed)
```

Answer (score 7):

Maybe does not fit your case, but this simple approach solve my problem in a similar case:

```
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bigSizeImage];
    [imageView sizeToFit];
```

After image view executes sizeToFit if you query the **imageView.frame.size** you will get the new image view size that fits the new image size.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4:** 
Frame for `.aspectFit` image is -

```
import AVFoundation
```

`let x: CGRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: myImage.size, insideRect: sampleImageView.frame)`

Comment: yes I done , but I don't have any space on y but it is returning as 40

Comment: That’s unexpected, have you tried with fresh view controller with single imageView with no constraints?

Comment: I tried on uiview xib , in that image view was there , origin x value is going to y and orgin y value is going to x . and I am using constraints.

Comment: like you said it was a issue because of the constraints @Jack

Answer (score 4):

```
+(UIImage *)CreateAResizeImage:(UIImage *)Img ThumbSize:(CGSize)ThumbSize 
{
    float actualHeight = Img.size.height;
    float actualWidth = Img.size.width;

    if(actualWidth==actualHeight) 
    {
        actualWidth = ThumbSize.width; 
        actualHeight = ThumbSize.height;
    }

    float imgRatio = actualWidth/actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = ThumbSize.width/ThumbSize.height; //320.0/480.0;


    if(imgRatio!=maxRatio)
    {
        if(imgRatio < maxRatio)
        {
            imgRatio = ThumbSize.height / actualHeight; //480.0 / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth;
            actualHeight = ThumbSize.height; //480.0;
        }
        else
        {
            imgRatio = ThumbSize.width / actualWidth; //320.0 / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight;
            actualWidth = ThumbSize.width; //320.0;
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        actualWidth = ThumbSize.width;
        actualHeight = ThumbSize.height; 
    }


    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, (int)actualWidth, (int)actualHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    [Img drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *NewImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return NewImg;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This single line can do this job

```
CGSize sizeInView = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(imgViewFake.image.size, imgViewFake.bounds).size;
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 UIImageView extension:

```
import AVFoundation

extension UIImageView {
  var imageSize: CGSize {
    if let image = image {
      return AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image.size, insideRect: bounds).size
    }
    return CGSize.zero
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is incredibly complicated and fails for some edge cases. I think this solution is much more elegant:

```
- (CGSize) sizeOfImage:(UIImage*)image inAspectFitImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView
{
    UKAssert(imageView.contentMode == UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit, @"Image View must use contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit");

    CGFloat imageViewWidth = imageView.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat imageViewHeight = imageView.bounds.size.height;

    CGFloat imageWidth = image.size.width;
    CGFloat imageHeight = image.size.height;

    CGFloat scaleFactor = MIN(imageViewWidth / imageWidth, imageViewHeight / imageHeight);

    return CGSizeMake(image.size.width*scaleFactor, image.size.height*scaleFactor);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution for same problem:
https://github.com/alexgarbarev/UIImageView-ImageFrame

Advantages:

- UIViewContentMode modes supported
- Can query for scales and for rect separately
- Can ask about image frame right from UIImageView

Answer (score 2):

Here's my AVFoundation-less solution.

First here's a CGSize extension for calculating a size that would fit another size:

```
extension CGSize
{
    func sizeThatFitsSize(_ aSize: CGSize) -> CGSize
    {
        let width = min(self.width * aSize.height / self.height, aSize.width)
        return CGSize(width: width, height: self.height * width / self.width)
    }
}
```

So the solution to OP's problem gets down to:

```
let resultSize = image.size.sizeThatFitsSize(imageView.bounds.size)
```

Also here's another extension for fitting a rect within another rect (it utilizes the above CGSize extension):

```
extension CGRect
{
    func rectThatFitsRect(_ aRect:CGRect) -> CGRect
    {
        let sizeThatFits = self.size.sizeThatFitsSize(aRect.size)

        let xPos = (aRect.size.width - sizeThatFits.width) / 2
        let yPos = (aRect.size.height - sizeThatFits.height) / 2

        let ret = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: sizeThatFits.width, height: sizeThatFits.height)
        return ret
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5** Extension

```
extension CGSize {
    func aspectFit(to size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let mW = size.width / self.width;
        let mH = size.height / self.height;
        
        var result = size
        if( mH < mW ) {
            result.width = size.height / self.height * self.width;
        }
        else if( mW < mH ) {
            result.height = size.width / self.width * self.height;
        }
        
        return result;
    }
    
    func aspectFill(to size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let mW = size.width / self.width;
        let mH = size.height / self.height;
        
        var result = size
        if( mH > mW ) {
            result.width = size.height / self.height * self.width;
        }
        else if( mW > mH ) {
            result.height = size.width / self.width * self.height;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following in Swift:

```
private func CGSizeAspectFit(aspectRatio:CGSize,boundingSize:CGSize) -> CGSize
{
    var aspectFitSize = boundingSize
    let mW = boundingSize.width / aspectRatio.width
    let mH = boundingSize.height / aspectRatio.height
    if( mH < mW )
    {
        aspectFitSize.width = mH * aspectRatio.width
    }
    else if( mW < mH )
    {
        aspectFitSize.height = mW * aspectRatio.height
    }
    return aspectFitSize
}

private func CGSizeAspectFill(aspectRatio:CGSize,minimumSize:CGSize) -> CGSize
{
    var aspectFillSize = minimumSize
    let mW = minimumSize.width / aspectRatio.width
    let mH = minimumSize.height / aspectRatio.height
    if( mH > mW )
    {
        aspectFillSize.width = mH * aspectRatio.width
    }
    else if( mW > mH )
    {
        aspectFillSize.height = mW * aspectRatio.height
    }
    return aspectFillSize
}
```

I'm using it like this:

```
let aspectSize  = contentMode == .ScaleAspectFill ? CGSizeAspectFill(oldSize,minimumSize: newSize) : CGSizeAspectFit(oldSize, boundingSize: newSize)

let newRect = CGRect( x: (newSize.width - aspectSize.width)/2, y: (newSize.height - aspectSize.height)/2, width: aspectSize.width, height: aspectSize.height)

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,IOSXColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRect(origin: CGPointZero,size: newSize))
CGContextDrawImage(context, newRect, cgImage)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know only the width of the imageview and when the height of the image is dynamic then you need to scale the image's height according to the given width to remove the white spaces above and below your image. Use the following method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8224161/2564702) to scale the height of the image according to the standard width of your screen.

```
-(UIImage*)imageWithImage: (UIImage*) sourceImage scaledToWidth: (float) i_width
{
    float oldWidth = sourceImage.size.width;
    float scaleFactor = i_width / oldWidth;

    float newHeight = sourceImage.size.height * scaleFactor;
    float newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight));
    [sourceImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

And call it from your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method like this:

```
UIImage *img = [dictImages objectForKey:yourImageKey]; // loaded the image
cell.imgView.image = [self imageWithImage:img scaledToWidth:self.view.frame.size.width];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 version**

```
extension CGSize {
   enum AspectMode {
       case fit
       case fill
   }

   enum Orientation {
       case portrait
       case landscape
   }

   func aspectCorrectSizeToFit(targetSize: CGSize, aspectMode: AspectMode = .fill) -> CGSize {
        switch aspectMode {
        case .fill: return aspectFill(targetSize: targetSize)
        case .fit: return aspectFit(targetSize: targetSize)
        }
    }

    var orientation: Orientation {
        if height >= width { return .portrait }
        else { return .landscape }
    }

    func aspectFit(targetSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let wRatio = targetSize.width / width
        let hRatio = targetSize.height / height
        let scale = min(wRatio, hRatio)
        return applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
    }

    func aspectFill(targetSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let wRatio = targetSize.width / width
        let hRatio = targetSize.height / height
        let scale = max(wRatio, hRatio)
        return applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned methods never give the required values.As aspect fit maintains the same aspect ratio we just need simple maths to calculate the values

Detect the aspect ratio

```
CGFloat imageViewAspectRatio = backgroundImageView.bounds.size.width / backgroundImageView.bounds.size.height;
CGFloat imageAspectRatio =  backgroundImageView.image.size.width / backgroundImageView.image.size.height;
CGFloat mulFactor = imageViewAspectRatio/imageAspectRatio;
```

Get the new values

```
CGFloat newImageWidth = mulFactor * backgroundImageView.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat newImageHeight = mulFactor * backgroundImageView.bounds.size.height;
```