# UIImage size in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have some `UIImage` and display it in `UIImageView`.

I need to use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` content mode.

Here is simple code:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
imageView.image = self.image;
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

How to know the size of an image which is displayed on the screen? Are there any solutions, properties or shall i calculate it manually?

**EDIT:**

I know about the property `image.size`.

`self.image.size` ->>> Original image size

`imageView.image.size` ->>> Size of the imageView, but not the displayed image.

I ask about the displayed size depending on the `imageView's size` and it's `contentmode`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856879/iphone-getting-the-size-of-an-image-after-aspectft

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a category on `UIImageView` that you can use to introspect the bounds of the displayed image based on the `UIViewContentMode` set on the image view:

```
@implementation UIImageView (JRAdditions)

- (CGRect)displayedImageBounds {
    UIImage *image = [self image];
    if(self.contentMode != UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit || !image)
        return CGRectInfinite;

    CGFloat boundsWidth  = [self bounds].size.width,
            boundsHeight = [self bounds].size.height;

    CGSize  imageSize  = [image size];
    CGFloat imageRatio = imageSize.width / imageSize.height;
    CGFloat viewRatio  = boundsWidth / boundsHeight;

    if(imageRatio < viewRatio) {
        CGFloat scale = boundsHeight / imageSize.height;
        CGFloat width = scale * imageSize.width;
        CGFloat topLeftX = (boundsWidth - width) * 0.5;
        return CGRectMake(topLeftX, 0, width, boundsHeight);
    }

    CGFloat scale = boundsWidth / imageSize.width;
    CGFloat height = scale * imageSize.height;
    CGFloat topLeftY = (boundsHeight - height) * 0.5;

    return CGRectMake(0, topLeftY, boundsWidth, height);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4):

In swift, same as @jacob-relkin

```
extension UIImageView {

    func displayedImageBounds() -> CGRect {

        let boundsWidth = bounds.size.width
        let boundsHeight = bounds.size.height
        let imageSize = image!.size
        let imageRatio = imageSize.width / imageSize.height
        let viewRatio = boundsWidth / boundsHeight
        if ( viewRatio > imageRatio ) {
            let scale = boundsHeight / imageSize.height
            let width = scale * imageSize.width
            let topLeftX = (boundsWidth - width) * 0.5
            return CGRectMake(topLeftX, 0, width, boundsHeight)
        }
        let scale = boundsWidth / imageSize.width
        let height = scale * imageSize.height
        let topLeftY = (boundsHeight - height) * 0.5
        return CGRectMake(0,topLeftY, boundsWidth,height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible. You can get the original Image size via following method

```
UIImage *image = imageView.image;
CGSize size = image.size;
```

**size**

The dimensions of the image, taking orientation into account. (read-only)

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) CGSize size
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also get it by using below method:

```
-(CGSize)imageSizeAfterAspectFit:(UIImageView*)imgview{


float newwidth;
float newheight;

UIImage *image=imgview.image;

if (image.size.height>=image.size.width){
    newheight=imgview.frame.size.height;
    newwidth=(image.size.width/image.size.height)*newheight;

    if(newwidth>imgview.frame.size.width){
        float diff=imgview.frame.size.width-newwidth;
        newheight=newheight+diff/newheight*newheight;
        newwidth=imgview.frame.size.width;
    }

}
else{
    newwidth=imgview.frame.size.width;
    newheight=(image.size.height/image.size.width)*newwidth;

    if(newheight>imgview.frame.size.height){
        float diff=imgview.frame.size.height-newheight;
        newwidth=newwidth+diff/newwidth*newwidth;
        newheight=imgview.frame.size.height;
    }
}

NSLog(@"image after aspect fit: width=%f height=%f",newwidth,newheight);

return CGSizeMake(newwidth, newheight);

}
```