# Place frame over UIImage not working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage, cgrect

I have a UIView that needs to be placed over a UIImage inside of a UIImageView at specific coordinates. The coordinates for the frame are referenced from the top left corner and have a specified width and height refrenced from the original image.

So, to make the frame, I am first getting the CGRect of the image using a category from the following post: [UIImage size in UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447814/uiimage-size-in-uiimageview)

I then get a scale factor to shrink the size of the frame by taking the original height, dividing it by the scaled height, and then dividing all of my values by that.

Lastly, I take the image CGRect and add the scaled position values of the frame to get my final CGRect for the view. However, the frame is always up and to the right of the desired location. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code (new is just a custom object with the correct frame parameters):

```
CGRect imageBounds = [self.imageView displayedImageBounds];


        float scaleFactor = AppDelegate.usedImage.size.height / imageBounds.size.height;

        new.height /= scaleFactor;
        new.width /= scaleFactor;
        new.positionX /= scaleFactor;
        new.positionY /= scaleFactor;

        UIView *faceRectView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        faceRectView.tag = idx;
        faceRectView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

      faceRectView.frame = CGRectMake((imageBounds.origin.x + new.positionX), (imageBounds.origin.y + new.positionY), new.width, new.height);


        [self.view addSubview:faceRectView];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CGPoint is a C structure that defines a point in a coordinate system. The origin of this coordinate system is at the top left on iOS and at the bottom left on OS X. In other words, the orientation of its vertical axis differs on iOS and OS X.

CGSize is another simple C structure that defines a width and a height value, and CGRect has an origin field, a CGPoint, and a size field, a CGSize. Together the origin and size fields define the position and size of a rectangle.

On iOS and OS X, an application has multiple coordinate systems. On iOS, for example, the application's window is positioned in the screen's coordinate system and every subview of the window is positioned in the window's coordinate system. In other words, the subviews of a view are always positioned in the view's coordinate system.

Take this example of a frame
[image]

and notice how it differs from the concept of bounds
[image]

CGGeometry Reference is a collection of structures, constants, and functions that make it easier to work with coordinates and rectangles. You may have run into code snippets similar to this:

**CGPoint point = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.origin.x + self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.origin.y + self.view.frame.size.height);**

Not only is this snippet hard to read, it's also quite verbose. We can rewrite this code snippet using two convenient functions defined in the CGGeometry Reference.

**CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(frame), CGRectGetMaxY(frame));**

To simplify the above code snippet, we store the view's frame in a variable named frame and use CGRectGetMaxX and CGRectGetMaxY. The names of the functions are self-explanatory.

The CGGeometry Reference defines functions to return the smallest and largest values for the x- and y-coordinates of a rectangle as well as the x- and y-coordinates that lie at the rectangle's center. Two other convenient getter functions are CGRectGetWidth and CGRectGetHeight.

Finally to conclude, check out the implementation of **CGRectMake**.

```js
CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height)
{
  CGRect rect;
  rect.origin.x = x; rect.origin.y = y;
  rect.size.width = width; rect.size.height = height;
  return rect;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great information. With this information, I managed to actually set up a UIImageView with the exact dimensions of the image, and scale it to fit in my superview, which gave me a better control over the size of the image.

Comment: I am glad, it served you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add Like that

```
faceRectView.frame = CGRectMake((0.0), (0.0), new.width, new.height);
```