# How to preserve image aspect ratio in iOS UIImageView when doing CIFilter, like CISepiaTone

Tags: ios, objective-c

In iOS, my UIImageView is "Aspect Fit", but when I do CIFilter of type e.g. "CISepiaTone",
I lose the original image aspect ratio. The image is stretched to whole UIImageView size.

How can I preserve the aspect ratio?

Comment: note: I tried (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645454/resize-uiimage-by-keeping-aspect-ratio-and-width) + (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
} but sometimes it rotates images by 90 degrees...

Answer (score 4):

If you are creating the filtered image with imageWithCIImage, then you won't get the proper aspect ratio.  Try creating a CGImageRef from the filter output CIImage and then creating the UIImage from the CGImageRef.

Example:

```
// assume you already have CIImage *outputImage and *inputImage declared

// convert to CGImage to maintain proper aspect ratio and dimensions
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef imageRef = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:inputImage.extent];
UIImage *filteredImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Then you can try setting the imageView with filteredImage.