# Change UiimageView Size of Image Size in ContentMode is AspectFit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, resize

I Am zooming in `UIImageview` but it show the blank space for the images that are landscape. I am using ContentMode `AspectFit` For `UIImageView` So how can i change the Height of Image view That can Fit to image height Because My Scrollview Works Perfectly But Imageview Not working Like scrollview also i am using autolayout . so How can i change the height of my `UIImageView` Depending on Image.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645454/resize-uiimage-by-keeping-aspect-ratio-and-width

Comment: By this you can maintain your aspect ratio & resize image.