# Resizing an image but preserving hard edges

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, image, image-resizing

I am using a piece of code from this link - [Resize UIImage by keeping Aspect ratio and width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645454/resize-uiimage-by-keeping-aspect-ratio-and-width), and it works perfectly, but I am wondering if it can be altered to preserve hard edges of pixels. I want to double the size of the image and keep the hard edge of the pixels.

```
class func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    let scale = newHeight / image.size.height
    let newWidth = image.size.width * scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight))
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

[What I want it to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WApqn.png)

[What it does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBt4s.png)

In Photoshop there is the nearest neighbour interpolation when resizing, is there something like that in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a bit more digging and found the answer -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25430447/4196903

but where

```
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh)
```

instead write

```
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, CGInterpolationQuality.None)
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the accepted answer, updated to Swift 5.

**Swift 5**

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Foo")!
let scale: CGFloat = 2.0

let newSize = image.size.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
context.interpolationQuality = .none
let newRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize)
image.draw(in: newRect)

let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: context.makeImage()!)
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CISampler`class (Which is only available in iOS 9) and need to create your own custom image processing filter for it i think

You can find more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_custom_filters/ci_custom_filters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH6-BCIEDBFC) and [here too](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185)