# ImageEdgeInsets Square Aspect Ratio

Tags: swift, imageedgeinsets

Is it possible to use ImageEdgeInsets to constrain an image to a square size? I have a UI Image inside of a button and I would like to make it a square size inside the button. Does ImageEdgeInsets offer the ability to maintain an aspect ratio? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

To maintain the aspect ratio, you should have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29534779/5899549) (it doesn't use ImageEdgeInsets)