# How to resize image to have maximum width of 1280px

Tags: swiftui, uiimage

How to resize image to have maximum width of 1280px while keeping the aspect ratio, before uploading image to server in SwiftUI AlamoFire.

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, maxWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    let oldWidth = image.size.width
    let oldHeight = image.size.height

    let scaleFactor = maxWidth / oldWidth
    let newHeight = oldHeight * scaleFactor
    let newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

i want resize my image before uploading to server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resize UIImage by keeping Aspect ratio and width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645454/resize-uiimage-by-keeping-aspect-ratio-and-width)

Answer (score 0):

We need to determine the scale and size, and then use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` to render the image:

```
extension UIImage {
    func scaled(toWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        let scale = toWidth / size.width
        let newHeight = size.height * scale
        let size = CGSize(width: toWidth, height: newHeight)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.scale = self.scale
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: format).image { _ in
            draw(in: rect)
        }
    }
}
```