# UIImage Aspect Fit when using drawInRect?

Tags: ios, uiimage

UIView provides for the "aspect fit" content mode. However, I've subclasses UIView and would like to draw a UIImage using drawInRect with an aspect fit. Is there any way for me to access that functionality without using a UIImageView?

Answer (score 41):

The math for that is a little bit hairy, but fortunately, here's a solution I prepared earlier:

```
- (UIImage *)imageScaledToSize:(CGSize)size
{
    //create drawing context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0f);

    //draw
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height)];

    //capture resultant image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}

- (UIImage *)imageScaledToFitSize:(CGSize)size
{
    //calculate rect
    CGFloat aspect = self.size.width / self.size.height;
    if (size.width / aspect <= size.height)
    {
        return [self imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(size.width, size.width / aspect)];
    }
    else
    {
        return [self imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(size.height * aspect, size.height)];
    }
}
```

The first function is equivalent to "scale to fill", the second (which calls the first) is equivalent to "aspect fit". These methods were written as a category on UIImage so to use them from within another class you'll need to tweak them by passing the image in as a second parameter (or just make a category on UIImage like I did).

Comment: I realize I'm kind of necroing a dead thread, but: why 0.0f for scale for the graphics context?

Comment: If you use 0.0 then it will select 1.0 or 2.0 automatically depending on whether the device has a Retina screen.

Comment: That's fantastic, it does.  thanks!  I never heard that one before.  I suppose I should read the documentation more often :)

Comment: Isn't the answer by @Antzi now better, where it is recommended to use AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(_ aspectRatio? Or is manually resizing still required?

Comment: @Crashalot ha, I never knew about that function. TIL.

Comment: My favorite comment of the year: `// return image`

Answer (score 38):

You have to draw in the rect provided by

**Swift:**

`func AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: CGSize, insideRect boundingRect: CGRect) -> CGRect`

**Objective-C:**

```
CGRect AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(CGSize aspectRatio, CGRect boundingRect);
```

See [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/1390116-avmakerectwithaspectratioinsider)

The aspect ratio is preserved and the drawing centred.

It works in absolutely all cases.

Comment: This is hands down the best solution, just remember to `import AVFoundation` if you want to use it.

Comment: This has saved me a lot of time - thanks! I had problems scaling SVG assets for notifications (UNNotificationAttachment) in a drawing context; they were always clipped or did not maintain aspect ratio. I tried all sorts of manual calculations but to no avail. This just worked!

Answer (score 14):

here's the solution

```
CGSize imageSize = yourImage.size;
CGSize viewSize = CGSizeMake(450, 340); // size in which you want to draw

float hfactor = imageSize.width / viewSize.width;
float vfactor = imageSize.height / viewSize.height;

float factor = fmax(hfactor, vfactor);

// Divide the size by the greater of the vertical or horizontal shrinkage factor
float newWidth = imageSize.width / factor;
float newHeight = imageSize.height / factor;

CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(xOffset,yOffset, newWidth, newHeight);
[image drawInRect:newRect];
```

-- courtesy https://stackoverflow.com/a/1703210

another alternative for aspect fit

```
-(CGSize ) getImageSize :(CGSize )imgViewSize andActualImageSize:(CGSize )actualImageSize {

     // imgViewSize = size of view in which image is to be drawn
     // actualImageSize = size of image which is to be drawn

     CGSize drawImageSize;

     if (actualImageSize.height > actualImageSize.width) {

        drawImageSize.height = imgViewSize.height;
        drawImageSize.width = actualImageSize.width/actualImageSize.height * imgViewSize.height;

     }else {

        drawImageSize.width = imgViewSize.width;
        drawImageSize.height = imgViewSize.width * actualImageSize.height /  actualImageSize.width;
     }
     return drawImageSize;
}
```

**Code for swift 3.0:**

```
func getAspectFitFrame(sizeImgView:CGSize, sizeImage:CGSize) -> CGRect{

    let imageSize:CGSize  = sizeImage
    let viewSize:CGSize = sizeImgView

    let hfactor : CGFloat = imageSize.width/viewSize.width
    let vfactor : CGFloat = imageSize.height/viewSize.height

    let factor : CGFloat = max(hfactor, vfactor)

    // Divide the size by the greater of the vertical or horizontal shrinkage factor
    let newWidth : CGFloat = imageSize.width / factor
    let newHeight : CGFloat = imageSize.height / factor

    var x:CGFloat = 0.0
    var y:CGFloat = 0.0
    if newWidth > newHeight{
        y = (sizeImgView.height - newHeight)/2
    }
    if newHeight > newWidth{
        x = (sizeImgView.width - newWidth)/2
    }
    let newRect:CGRect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: newWidth, height: newHeight)

    return newRect

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a helper CGSize extension that you might find useful:

```
extension CGSize
{
    func sizeThatFitsSize(_ aSize: CGSize) -> CGSize
    {
        let width = min(self.width * aSize.height / self.height, aSize.width)
        return CGSize(width: width, height: self.height * width / self.width)
    }
}
```

Then in `-drawInRect:` implementation one would do the following:

```
let imageSizeThatFitsViewBounds = self.image.size.sizeThatFitsSize(self.bounds.size)
let imageRectX = (self.bounds.size.width - imageSizeThatFitsViewBounds.width) / 2
let imageRectY = (self.bounds.size.height - imageSizeThatFitsViewBounds.height) / 2
let imageRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: imageRectX, y: imageRectY), size: imageSizeThatFitsViewBounds)
```

Answer (score 2):

this might help you, give it a try

```
UIImage *logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];

float newHeight = ((logoImage.size.height / logoImage.size.width) * 100.0);
CGRect newLogoImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80.0, newHeight);
[logoImage drawInRect:newLogoImageRect];
```

specify your maximum height instead of 100.0 and maximum width instead of 80.0

Answer (score 1):

The following will let you determine the size to draw in. You specify the aspect ratio and the bounding size to fit into.

[CGSizeAspectFit & CGSizeAspectFill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17948778/543814)