# Aspect Ratio issues when redrawing in Core Graphics context

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, drawrect, cgcontext, aspect-ratio

I am redrawing images in a `CGContextRef` graphics context, however, when I draw the images, their aspect ratio is wrong. In the picture below, the graphics context is the black square (a separate `UIView` class), and the pictures being displayed are selected from the red carousel below it. I've looked at a bunch of posts, but can't figure out where to fix it.

[image]

Here is my `drawRect` method. I don't know where I can set the `contentMode`, since there is not `UIImageView`, only `UIImages.`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dna = _mini.dna;
    NSString *directory = @"FacialFeatures";

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(context, self.bounds);

    //flip the coordinates for Core Graphics coordinates
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -self.bounds.size.height);

    for (id key in dna) {
        NSString *value = [dna objectForKey:key];
        if (![value isEqualToString:@""]) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", directory, key, value]];
            CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, image.CGImage);
        }
    }
}
```

For bonus help, I also don't know why the background of the Graphics Context is black. I've tried setting it in interface builder and in my init method but it seems all settings are ignored. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have cleared the rect using

```
CGContextClearRect(context, self.bounds);
```

This will make your context and view transparent so, Check your super view's color may be it's black. If you want it white you can do like

```
CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
```

**Reason of image stretching**

`CGContextDrawImage` will scale image to fit into specified rect. So,try to provide a rect in a such a way that it's aspect ratio will be maintain.

Here I have provide few link which using some calculation to calculate rect or size

[Resize image with keeping aspect ratio](http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2009/05/06/Resize-image-and-keep-aspect-ratio.aspx)
[UIImage aspect fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858404/uiimage-aspect-fit-when-using-drawinrect)

Comment: Great, thanks! The image scaling code worked perfectly. It was still stretching but then I realised I was passing the wrong rect to CGContextDrawImage, so changed it to CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, scaledImage.size.width, scaledImage.size.height), scaledImage.CGImage);

Answer (score 0):

Include this line and check in the above method:-

```
[super drawRect:rect];
```