# take a screenshot of UIImageView for the content mode Aspect fit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have `imageView` with Aspect fit mode. I have added the another view on the `imageView`.
I want to take a screenshot of the `imageView` without compressing (as same resolution as before).

I have tried the following code

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(imgView.image.size.width, imgView.image.size.height), NO, 1.0);
    [imgView drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgView.image.size.width, imgView.image.size.height) afterScreenUpdates:YES];
   UIImage *  Image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But the end image is streach. What should I do?

**I think it includes the transparent portion here. is there any way to not to include in that**

Comment: If you are using the retina display then try to increase the height  and width of the cropping section by twice or four times and let me if it works. i.e. (imgView.image.size.width*2,imgView.image.size.height * 2) or (imgView.image.size.width*4,imgView.image.size.height * 4).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858404/uiimage-aspect-fit-when-using-drawinrect

Comment: how you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);

[imgView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *newImageWithMyImageView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because the image's height was a decimal, I casted it to integer value and the image is not stretched any more.

So try this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(imgView.image.size.width, imgView.image.size.height), NO, 1.0);
[imgView drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, (int) imgView.image.size.width, (int)imgView.image.size.height) afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *  Image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```