# Merge UIImage and UIBezierPath into 1 UIImage

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I have a view that has a `UIImage` and a `DrawView` as subviews. The draw view responds to touches and creates a `UIBezierPath` for drawing *on* the image. When the user accepts their change I need to merge the underlying `UIImage` and any `UIBezierPath`'s created into a single `UIImage`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make that `UIBazierPath` a public property of your `DrawView`, and keep updating it when user is drawing from within `DrawView`. When user hits the Accept button, use following code to simply Create a `UIImageContext` and *draw* both, the `sourceImage` and `bezierPath` over the context. Finally take whatever is drawn on the context in a `resultImage`.

```
UIBezierPath *path = drawView.Path // Your Bezier Path in DrawView
UIImage *sourceImage = sourceImageView.image; // Your Source Image from ImageView.
UIImage *resultImage = nil;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sourceImage.size);
[sourceImage drawInRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, sourceImage.size}];
[path stroke]; //Fill or Stroke path as you need.
[path fill];

resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); //taking the merged result from context, in a new Image. This is your required image.

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//Use resultImage as you want.
```

Comment: Could you please add more details about your answer?

Comment: I used this in combination with http://stackoverflow.com/a/14119250/531479 and it was what I needed.