# Get dimension or CGRect of UIImage after AspectFit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, bounds

I am just finding the way to get the image size whenever it aspect fit to imageview. but didn't get any proper way to get the image dimension. [image] I just want to calculate the difference between the imageview and the actual image in the imageview. Please advice.

Comment: Your image is loaded from backend service? or is local resource

Comment: Check below link it may useful to you  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6284498/5184217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, when the image is showed, its size(instance of Image) doesn't change unless you call compressing image functions.

The only problem is how it's drawn on ImageView.
When you use aspect fit to imageview, the image is drawn keeping its own rate between width and height based on the larger one of width and height of ImageView.

So, how to calculate the drawn image size is showed above by @Luan Tran.

Thanks

Hope it help

Comment: Let me try this

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
 CGSize imageViewSize = imageView.bounds.size;
 CGSize imageSize = image.size;
 CGFloat minFactor = imageViewSize.width / imageSize.width;
 if (imageViewSize.height / imageSize.height < minFactor) 
 {
     minFactor = imageViewSize.height / imageSize.height;
 }

 CGSize resultSize = CGSizeMake(minFactor * imageSize.width, minFactor * imageSize.height);
```

Hope it help.