# iOS - Layout UIImageView's subview on the scaleaspectfit UIImageView's image

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uiimageview

I have UITableView, where is a UIStackView with same views(different content only) on each cell.(The tableView's cell is shown below)

[image: UITableView cell]

The view consists of UIImageView and UILabel above. The UIImageView's content is set to .scaleAspectFit, because of keeping ratio. I have a problem with adding a new image layer (subview) to imageView, which has to perfectly overlap current image, but I can't fit on image properly with autolayout, because I know only UIImageView's anchor, not image's anchor (it doesn't exists).

PS: I have tried to use `imageview.image.size.width`, to set width and height, but it's also useless.

Current code of adding subview using autolayout:

```
func addStripe(){
        let stripeLayer = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "book_new"))
        imageView.addSubview(stripeLayer)

        stripeLayer.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        stripeLayer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        stripeLayer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stripeLayer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        stripeLayer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Aaaand there is a result of `addStripe` function (the wrong one)

[image: And there is a result]

Thanks everyone for your time!

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278876/how-to-know-the-image-size-after-applying-aspect-fit-for-the-image-in-an-uiimage/43114960#43114960). It tells you how you get the resulting size of your image. It should then be easy to play you stripe correctly.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner It works perfectly! Please add your comment as an answer, because of marking it as a solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ReinhardManner's comment helped me and it works. This single line fix my problem

```
let sizeInView = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: imgViewFake.image.size, insideRect: imgViewFake.bounds).size
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set frame of your `stripeLayer` equal to `imageView`. You can do this with init method of `UIImageView` like this:

```
let stripeLayer = UIImageView(frame: imageView.frame)
stripeLayer.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "book_new")
imageView.addSubview(stripeLayer.image)
```

I hope it help you

Comment: It's wrong, because UIImage is not a view, that means i can't add image as subview :)

Comment: @prone666 but I used UIImageView, not UIImage

Comment: Yes, of course but on the line 3 of your code snippet, you're adding `stripeLayer.image`

Comment: @prone666 no. "image" is an attribute of UIImageView you can use it to set image of UIImageView.